# Jenkins: Failed to connect to repository: 128: stdout: stderr: Logon failed

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a Jenkins and Maven CI process. I am currently getting the following error message while updating `Repository URL` under `Source Code management` tab.

> Failed to connect to repository: 128: stdout: stderr: Logon failed

[image]

Comment: It's your task not stack overflow

Comment: I meant I need to complete this task!

Comment: Who stops you to complete your task!!?? And you didn't specify Jenkins job script and Maven CI process

Comment: hahaha... I am stuck and hence I have asked for help. and please read the entire details, you should get it

Comment: This question already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557998/jenkins-failed-to-connect-to-repository

Comment: Sorry, but error is not the same I am getting "returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt. "

Comment: Look this similar answer and make sure you are using correct git credential https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802507/error-while-creating-new-jenkins-job-failed-to-connect-to-repository-status-c If still issue I can only vote up your issue.